# Using a javascript function with a checkbox array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, checkbox

so i have a checkbox array name "vote[]" and i want to call a function to tick all of them, atm my function is like this

```
function checkAll(field)  
{  
    for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)  
        field[i].checked = true ;  
}
```

and i call it like this

```
checkAll(document.form.vote)
```

but it doesnt work... wutdo?

Thanks, Ben

p.s i have tried to doing

```
checkAll(document.form.vote[])
```

and it doesnt work.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
checkAll(document.form['vote[]'])
```

**Explanation:** `[]` is part of the name but if you write it like `form.vote[]`, it would be interpreted as JavaScript (probably invalid). Luckily, in JavaScript there are two ways to access object properties: Dot notation,  `foo.bar`,  and array notation, `foo['bar']`. The latter one comes in handy if the property is not a valid JavaScript identifier.

**Further suggestion:** As we don't know how your HTML look like `document.form` might also not work. I suggest to give the form an ID and call:

```
checkAll(document.getElementById('yourFormID')['vote[]'])
```

**Update:**

Works for me: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/us4Hw/)

Comment: Doesnt Work :S any other ideas?

Comment: tried both and neither worked :S my html is simple ill copy both the button and the javascript

Comment: <input type="button" name="selectall" value="Select All" class="btn" OnClick="checkAll(document.getElementById("form")["vote[]"])
" />

Comment: function checkAll(field)
{
for (i = 0; i < field.length; i++)
 field[i].checked = true ;
}

Comment: @Ben Mills: You have a quoting error. Look at it precisely: `OnClick="checkAll(document.getElementById("form")["vote[]"])"`. You cannot use double quotes inside a double quoted string. Use single quotes instead: `OnClick="checkAll(document.getElementById('form')['vote[]'])"` . Have a look at the demo.

Comment: i cant because im using php to echo it with echo '';

Comment: @Ben Mills: Then escape the inner quotes with `\'`. E.g. `echo 'OnClick="checkAll(document.getElementById(\'form\')[\'vote[]\'])"'` or simply don't `echo` HTML (that would be the preferred way).

Answer (score 2):

Although the original poster was able to get this working, another way (avoiding the getElementsByTagName call) would be:

```
checkAll(document.formname.elements['vote[]'])
```

Hope that helps someone in the future. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this with by filtering with checkbox only i.e `type='checkbox'`

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    if(boxes.type='Checkbox'){
        for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
            if (boxes[i].name == 'vote[]' ) {
                boxes[i].checked = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this with `document.getElementsByName` instead:

```
checkAll(document.getElementsByName('vote[]'));
```

---

If that doesn't work, have a go with this, looping through all `input` elements.

```
var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    if (boxes[i].name == 'vote[]') {
        boxes[i].checked = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt Work :S any other ideas?